# dm-script function to detect digiScan overhead time

Tags: hardware, dm-script

Is there an equivalent/similar function to `DSisAcquisitionActive()`?

In my GMS 1.93, DM complains "No match for dsisacquisitionactive()".

Wondering if there is alternative function for old systems. I need to wait the DigiScan overhead time is over before acquiring another STEM to avoid system crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, I'm not aware of an 'earlier' command which would do that.

Hardware scripting has only been introduced with GMS 2.3. All commands before that time were Gatan-intern R&D only. But as they are the "basis" for the later suppored commands, some of them exist in older versions.

The F1 help documenation lists the supported commands and it also states the *version history*. Most often it is *"introduced in ...."* and those are usually working in earlier versions. The command you've mentioned, however, reads *"Added as new command"* so it has been created with that version

[image]

However, you should be able to "estimate" that time pretty accurately when you know pixel-dwell-time and flyback time. There is a certain "overhead" for loading the hardware, but that should be constant and independent of the actual acquisition paramters to a large extend.
Maybe plot several acquistions times as function of the pixel-dwelltime and/or image size (at constant fly-back) and do a linear regression to get an idea of that value.

Another idea I would try would be to put the acqusitions start code into a Try{}Catch{} loop and use the exception thrown by the Digiscan still being active to wait. That's pretty ugly and I'm not sure it would work, but it's worth a  shot when you're forced to remain with old software...